# Does the complexity of a basis function correspond to the number of DOF required to select it?

Tags: regression, model-selection, inference, degrees-of-freedom

My general question is whether the number of DOF lost when selecting a basis function from library is dependent on the complexity of the basis function.

More specifically: we try to fit a curve, which is perturbed during a certain time. To model the perturbation we use a library of basis functions starting from the earliest possible moment to the end of the data (so onset is not estimated). These basis functions have a standardized amplitude of 1 and are therefore scaled to match the observed data.

[image: Example curve. Full line represent orignal curve. Dots are observed data that show a perturbation between 18 - 50 min.]

The basis functions are created using 3 parameters. Since we also estimate the scaling factor, we now consider this model to use 4 DOF (+ those used for the estimation of the global curve). However, intuitively, it would seem that we could defend using only 2 DOF, since there is 1) the scaling factor, 2) the selection of the basis function from the library, which is done with weighted non-linear sum of squared errors.

Would you have an idea whether this intuition is correct, and what formal way we can use to show this?

Many thanks in advance!